# Qual è il significato di "paladino" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita, che si sente avvampare, sempre piú a disagio, risponde che sul conto di Merluzzo sono sempre circolate molte leggende, che era un ladro, una specie di bandito, un **paladino**, un pirata, storie cosí – ma lei non gli ha mai dato peso perché Rocco, cioè Merluzzo, cioè questo Meize, era un inquilino molto generoso, bravo in tutti i sensi e lei non lo credeva capace di far del male a nessuno.

Non riesco a capire il senso del termine "paladino" in questo brano, soprattutto perché il testo sembra suggerire che si tratti di qualcosa di negativo, però le accezioni di questo vocabolo che ho trovato sui dizionari sembrano avere una connotazione positiva. Qualcuno di voi avrebbe idea di cosa possa significare?

Comment: Non vedo perché dovrebbe essere negativo; anche Robin Hood era dagli uni considerato un paladino, dagli altri un bandito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato, preso dal [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/paladino/), è quello figurato:

> Difensore; fautore, sostenitore leale e disinteressato: *farsi p. degli oppressi, degli emarginati, dei poveri; erigersi a p. della libertà, della democrazia, della pace;*

e viene utilizzato correntemente come sinonimo di persona nobile, valorosa e cavalleresca, animata da ideali positivi e difensore appunto di oppressi e ultimi (l'origine della parola indicava un cavaliere di alta nobiltà e valore che viveva alla corte di Carlo Magno e lo accompagnava in guerra).
Non esistono "paladini" dell'ingiustizia o del male, a meno che non si tratti per esempio di [parodie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superciuk).

L'autrice del brano vuol dire che sul conto del personaggio (Merluzzo) circolavano un sacco di voci "leggendarie" e contraddittorie: alcune lo dipingono appunto come un farabutto (ladro, bandito, pirata), altre come una persona nobile e disinteressata (paladino). Da notare che questi sostantivi sembrano tutti voler insistere nel conferire a Merluzzo un'aura avventurosa e quasi "mitologica".

Comment: Difensore, sostenitore di che cosa? Forse sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_384.pdf) si trova qualche accezione più adatta.

Comment: ho provato ad ampliare la risposta.

Comment: A me sembra che il significato sia quello base, di cavaliere (di Carlo Magno). Poi, è indubbio che a ognuno dei termini elencati (e che fanno riferimento a personaggi di storie avventurose) possono affiancarsi dei giudizi di valore.